# Javascript to make Manage My Kindle delete matching items?

Tags: javascript, kindle, calibre

I have a kindle and use [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com) to send it documents. Because I have Personal Documents archival enabled (and don't want to disable it), Amazon stores all of my news items in the archive. These extraneous items make it hard to find the books that I want archived.

I found the code below [here](http://www.amazon.com/forum/kindle?_encoding=UTF8&cdForum=Fx1D7SY3BVSESG&cdPage=1&cdThread=Tx1NTIGX6GSG007) to delete all items as a bookmarklet. How can I filter to it to only delete some of them? I'm not very familiar with Javascript, but learning is fun, right?

```
javascript:(function(){
    var v = new RegExp("PersonalDocuments");
    if (!v.test(document.URL)) {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        a=document.getElementsByClassName('rowBodyCollapsed');
        for(var i = 0;
            i<a.length;
            i++){
            Fion.deleteItem('deleteItem_'+a[i].getAttribute('asin'));
        };
        return;
    }
    })();
```

Answer (score 1):

I find the Kindle Library Powerpack script quite handy. 
Which provides a checkbox for every item in the personal documents.
It needs the greasemonkey to be installed, that is, used in firefox only, maybe google chrome is 
also OK, but I'm not sure.
greasemonkey addon for firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

the script: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/130289